# This variable has not been assigned a value (a global variable)

Tags: autohotkey

I just discovered that if I try to use a global variable inside a function that is declared after a simple hotkey, a warning appears saying that this global variable doesn't has a value.

Illustration:

[image: code and warning image]

In this example, when I press Shift + l the warning appears.

Can anyone explain ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables have to be declared in the [auto-execute section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) or within a hotkey/hotstring/or another function.

```
#Warn
global a := "10/10"  ; super-global variable

$+p:: Pause

$+1:: foo()

foo(){  
    MsgBox % "a = " . a
}
```

or
to access global variables within a function you need to add global within the function:

```
#Warn

a := "10/10"  ; global variable

$+p:: Pause

$+1:: foo()

foo(){
    global
    MsgBox % "a = " . a
}
```

or:

```
#Warn

$+1:: 
    global a := "10/10"
    foo()
return

$+p:: Pause

foo(){
    MsgBox % "a = " . a
}
```

For more details read [Local and Global Variables](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Locals)

Comment: What if I want to access a variable from another script? I've tried seemingly everything.